# Gamma Symbols in flat space

Tags: differential-geometry, cartan-geometry

Let $M$ a flat torsion free four dimensional  manifold and let  $t$ be a real function on it.

Define  $$S_p=\{q\in M: t(p)=t(q)\}$$

than we can show that $S_p$ is a flat 3 dimensional manifold.

Now given a moving frame  $e_\mu$ in $M$ such that $De_0=0$, where $D$ is a covariant derivative , define

$$\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu \nu}=\theta^\rho(D_{e_\mu}e_\nu)$$

where $\theta^\rho $ is the dual moving frame

Now suppose that $e_j \in TS_p$ for $j=1,2,3$, how can we proof that
$$\Gamma^{k}_{i j}=0$$

for $k,i,j=1,2,3$ ?

Comment: You typed $De_0=0$. Did you mean $De_\mu = 0$ for all $\mu$? When you say $M$ is "flat torsion free," what precisely do you mean?

Comment: I do not understand the sentence "than we can show that $_p$ is a flat 3-dimensional manifold": No, you cannot show this in general since it is true for some functions $t$ and false for other functions. Are you **assuming** that $t$ is such that the level set is a flat manifold?

Comment: i will update my question soon